# Django middleware: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'background_color' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, django-middleware, django-1.11

I'm trying to randomise certain elements of my theme across a website I'm building. I thought it might be quite nice to experiment with defining some custom middleware to handle this. But it looks like I've gone wrong somewhere:

middleware.py:

```
class RandomThemeAppearanceMiddleware(object):

    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):

        theme = {
            background_color: '#266040',
            contrast: '#3bbfad',
            color: '#ffffff',
        }

        background_colors = ['#266040', '#009a16', '#015e85', '#d6006d']

        background_color = random.choice(background_colors)

        if background_color == '#266040':
            theme['contrast'] = '#3bbfad'
        elif background_color == '#009a16':
            theme['contrast'] = '#fedf21'
        elif background_color == '#015e85':
            theme['contrast'] = '#0590b3'
        elif background_color == '#d6006d':
            theme['contrast'] = '#f97fb5'
        else:
            pass

        theme['background_color'] = background_color

        request.background_color = theme['background_color']
        request.contrast = theme['contrast']
        request.color = theme['color']

        return self.get_response(request)
```

Django debug is telling me the following:

```
UnboundLocalError at /
local variable 'background_color' referenced before assignment
```

Can anyone shed any light on why this is error is being thrown?

Comment: Is there a stacktrace? Where is this happening?

Comment: @BaileyParker Hi Bailey, please ignore. I failed to put quotes around theme['foo'] in my dictionary - what a dummy! :D